# How to use at symbol (@) inside live template in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've created a live template as follows

```
<button type="button" @click="$click$">$label$</button>
```

the shortcut for it is `btnbtn`

When I expand the template it omits the whole `@click=""` part and expands as follows:

```
<button type="button">(cusror here)</button>
```

I tried escaping the @ sign as \@ and then it works but it leaves the slash in place?

I guess I'm doing something wrong but just not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite likely it's some sort of Live Template parser limitation or something.

Possible workaround is to use additional variable for `@` and provide default value for it (so it never gets triggered for completion):

1. Edit Live Template content to be `<button type="button" $at$click="$click$">$label$</button>`
2. Click on `Edit Variables` button
3. For our artificial `at` variable -- enter `"@"` in "Default value" and check "Skip if defined" column.

[image]

**P.S.** The same variable can be re-used many times (if you need more than one `@attribute` in your snippet.

---

I still suggest filing a Bug ticket to the [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) -- I could not find exact match myself (lots of tickets for "live templates" to go through ([1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=%22live%20template%22), [2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q="live%20template"))) ... but I definitely remember seeing either ticket or forum post/question with similar issue.

Comment: That's a rather clever hack! :) I will try to find it on the bug tracker or create one if needed. Thank you so much.